# Bootable USB or Pendrive are not detected in Raspberry pi 3B+ for data transfer or format

Tags: pi-3, usb, hardware, data-transfer

I want to copy a file raspberry pi 3B+ to my Desktop machine. I had plugged the USB pen-drive in raspberry pi 3B+. But pen-drive is not recognized. Did I missed anything as in case of pi?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please execute the command `lsblk` on the command line when the pendrive is attached. Then edit your question and copy and paste the output into the question.

Comment: normal pendrive is detected but bootable pendrive for format is not detecting.

Answer (score 0):

How and where do you check for the USB? Check in `/mnt` for USB drives connected as there is no notification when I connect any USB to my pi. I've to check there always.

Comment: When I connect the USB to RPI It does not pop up any notification. And, I checked in the directory structure the USB name not appears.

Comment: Do you want me to check in /mnt directory. @theashwanisingla

Comment: Yes, I mean the same. And, if it is still not there, plz check the file format of the drive. If it is NTFS, then you need to install a separate userspace driver to be able to write to the NTFS drives as it is strictly Read-only access. plz Let me know.

Comment: Sure i will check and update you @theashwanisingla